# Browsing lines/columns in a big file in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work with big flat database files which I like to inspect at line/column.

I have a tool which generates a log with hundreds of lines like:

```
code --goto path/to/my/file:line:column
```

Visiting one such a spot works ok if I throw one such a line into the command line window and click it from there, but not from the editor (at least I have not found the way)

I would like to be able to have this log file open in the VSCode editor and hover/click in every line which would take me to the spot I want to visit in the big db file. Is this possible at all?

Should I convert my log file to some script format which supports the hover and click functionality?

Is there otherwise any extension available which can do the trick here?

Thanks a lot.
Miguel

**Edit**

Using HTML Related Links v0.9.0

I guess we're almost there but it's still not working for me.

The concrete scenario I have is: I have a file

`d:\Users\Abc.def\Git\lingware-data\test\spx\spm\spm_cfg3\spm_cfg3_tst_row_valid_lng_abbr.dbr`

containing several lines of the type

`code --goto d:\Users\Abc.def\Git\lingware-data\dct\spx\dct.u08:176:36`

(probably `code` is not needed, I tried with and without it)

In my `settings.json` file:

```json
"files.associations": { ".u08": "csv (pipe)", ".dbr": "html" },
"editor.largeFileOptimizations": false,
"html-related-links.include": {
   "html": [
      { "find": "--goto ([a-z:]+[^:]+):(\\d+):(\\d+)",
        "filePath": "$1",
        "lineNr": "$2",
        "charPos": "$3"
      }
   ]
}
```

if I use `"plaintext"` as languageId I don't get the HTML related links section displayed in the Explorer area, so I am using `"html"` - I have updated to v0.9.0 of the extension, and what I continue seeing in the explorer view is:

`"d:\Users\Abc.def\Git\lingware-data\dct\spx\dct.u08 d:\Users\Abc.def\Git\lingware-data\test\spx\spm\spm_cfg3\d:\Users\Abc.def\Git\lingware-data\dct\spx\dct.u08"`

If I click on it nothing happens I hope this is more or less clear.

What am I doing wrong?

*** edit ***
Installed v0.9.1. Enabled Developer console to debug click behavior on a row. What get now is:

```
[Extension Host] Clicked on: d:\Users\Miguel.Duran\Git\lingware-data\dct\spx\dct.u08
console.ts:137 [Extension Host]     goto: 175:28
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) v0.9.0 (it not only applies to HTML)

Define this in `settings.json`

```json
"html-related-links.include": {
    "plaintext": [
      { "find": "--goto ([^:]+):(\\d+):(\\d+)",
        "filePath": "$1",
        "isAbsolutePath": true,
        "lineNr": "$2",
        "charPos": "$3"
      }
    ]
  },
"html-related-links.removePathFromLabel": true
```

After loading the log file you can lock the Explorer View `HTML RELATED LINKS` to this file. Use lock button in top right of the view. Now only changes to this log file will update the view.

In an absolute path the label will contain the path and the view adds the directory path at the end. You can remove the path from the label with the setting `html-related-links.removePathFromLabel`

Click on a row in the view and that file will be opened to the given `line:char` position.

If on Windows the path is absolute you have to specify the drive first because it contains a `:`

```
"find": "--goto ([a-z]:[^:]+):(\\d+):(\\d+)"
```

**Edit**

There was a small typo in the regular expression string (need escaping the escape char).

Add possibility for absolute paths.

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting option. I installed the extension and configure html-related-links.include as suggested. I had to use "html" and rename my log file to .html as well, otherwise it would not be parsed. My problem now is that the built filePath is the concatenation of the path/to/my/log_file + path given in the "find" property. My log file can be stored anywehre and contains already the absolute path to the file to visit, so it should not interfere in building the path. Can you please help me clarify how I should set it up properly? Thanks.

Comment: I have looked at the code and now only relative paths are allowed, I will modify the extension and allow the use of full path specifications. Now only paths that are in the workspace are allowed. No need to set everything to `html`, find out what the languageId is of the log file (see lower right status bar)

Comment: @Miguel Look at v0.9.0

Comment: @Miguel I have edited your question using the previous comments to make it a bit more readable. Look closely at the `settings.json` section of the answer, you have forgotten to add `"isAbsolutePath": true,` and also handy is the `"html-related-links.removePathFromLabel": true`, if you hover over a row in the view you get a tooltip with the file it will try to load when clicked

Comment: @Miguel regarding the languageID, try to add `"html-related-links.alwaysShow": true` to settings.json and use `plaintext` in the config

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I overlooked indeed `"isAbsolutePath": true`. My regex was ok, I had modified it earlier. Now I get the list loaded using "plaintext" and my mouse hover shows me the correct path to the log file... but clicking on the rows does not open anything. I use `--goto` in my entries and the regex of the "find" property is `--goto ([a-z]:[^:]+):(\\d+):(\\d+)`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Miguel Does the file mentioned in the tooltip really exists? When you try to parse only the file name, remove `lineNr` and `charPos` lines, any different

Comment: Nothing wrong with the path to the file, it does exist. I also removed lineNr and charPos, adjusted the regex to parse it, but same outcome, nothing opens when clicking on the link. Is there any (error) log I could check somewhere? I don't know javascript but if you send me some code snippet to add to extension.js to adapt it for logging, I could try it..

Comment: @Miguel with v0.9.1 you can enable logging `"html-related-links.enableLogging": true` of what happens when you click on a row. If all goes well you see 3 times the file path logged `Clicked`, `Document` and `Editor`. I needed to uninstall first, Bugfix updates are not done immediate.

Comment: @Miguel Enable the Developer Tools from the `Help` menu and use the `Console` tab

Comment: Installed latest 0.9.1, enabled Developer Tools > Console

Comment: Updated the initial question text with my findings from the debug console. I didn't get `Document` nor `Editor`.

Comment: @Miguel For me this only happens when the file I clicked on does NOT exist. What happen when you use **File** | **Open File...** and the path as displayed in the console. What happens if you edit the log file with a very simple file (path) (1 subdir of d:\) that you know exist?

Comment: the file is perfectly accessible, I can open it all right via File|Open File. There is no difference if I use a shorter/simpler path. What I currently do to work with the log file (not optimal) is, I open a terminal, `type` the contents of the file in there, and from there I can ctrl+click on the links to the source file. This works, but is a bit clumsy. It's very strange your extension is not working in this case, but if you think there's nothing to do, so be it. Thanks for your support anyway.

Comment: @Miguel I have found a little bug, it does not show error messages, fixed it in v0.9.2. When the open document fails you get an ErrorMessage box (lower right)

Comment: OK, the error message now shows more light to the problem: `Error: cannot open file://.... . Detail: Files above 50MB cannot be synchronized with extensions`. My file is indeed 54MB, and it can be as much as double big in size.

Comment: @Miguel I will file an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111849) with VSC asking how to load BIG files with extensions. Maybe you can upvote the issue (send a thumbs-up)

Comment: @Miguel They replied that is by design and will not be changed. I will try a different loading method

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. FYI, I am not blocked, I can further work with an alternative. I read the reply they gave you and I don't quite agree with their wording of "monstruous documents". This is 2020, text files getting this big is not an exception anymore. And besides, my file is not a document but a piece of data/code, something which is supposed to be the core business of VSCode IMO....

Comment: @Miguel Can you try the new **Open File or Create File** button on the item line in v0.12.0 and see if the 50MB limit also applies to this method.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to have this log file open in the VSCode editor and hover/click in every line which would take me to the spot I want to visit in the big db file.
> Is this possible at all?

If you visualize your file in a VSCode terminal, VSCode 1.70 (July 2022) will offer a way.

See [issue 140780](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140780) ("Jump to line+column in terminal links (format `<path> l:c)`"), [PR 153957](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/153957) ("Detect terminal links with space, then `line:col`") and [PR 155904](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/155904) ("Ensure folders with spaces don't impact link line/col")

> To test, you can open a terminal and run `echo ./myFile.txt 10:5` (replacing the filename with one that exists).
>
> When you click to open the file, it should open to line 10, column 5.

This is available today (July 2022) in [Code insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

[image: Ensure folders with spaces don't impact link line/col]